# How to assign a python variable value to a html button's id?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to assign the value contained in a python variable to an `html` button's `id` attribute .

I tried something like:

```
 print '<td><input type="button" value="WRITE" id=%s></input></td>' % pinNo
```

but it doesn't work for me.

What is the easiest way to achieve my goal here? Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? Where is this HTML going? How are you outputting it to the browser?

Comment: Sure it can work...what do you mean about it can't work?

Comment: Indeed, there is no problem with [using python's `print` for generating `HTML`](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_hello_world)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using (old) string formatting on a number. But I would suggest to use the [newer syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and write it like this:

```
print '<td><input type="button" value="WRITE" id="{}"></input></td>'.format(pinNo)
```

Not really necessary, but I would also put double quotes around the `id` value